# edit uploded file list

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc

i have a form where i am uploading multiple file . It is working nice.After uploaded files are stored in local storage.This is my model

```
@Entity
public class Image implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "CAPTION")
private String caption;

@Column(name = "IMAGE_PATH")
private String imagePath;

@Column(name = "IMAGE_NAME")
private String imageName;

@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_VIEW")
private Integer numberOfView;

@Column(name = "CONTENT_TYPE")
private String contentType;

@Column(name = "EXTENSION_TYPE")
private String extensionType;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo();

// @Column(name = "CAPTION")
@Transient
private MultipartFile file;

 }
```

you can see there is a property named file which i used to upload file.now my question is after uploading how can i edit  uploaded file.i uploaded a file then i want to change the uploaded file,i want to upload another file in same image object.if user click edit link uploaded file will be appear in a form , from where he can change the file.How can i do it??